# Principle of analytical continuation proof confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on a region $D$ and assume I can find a sequence $\{w_k\}$ in $D$ s.t. $w_k \to z_0$ w/ $z_0 \in D$, $w_k \not = z_0$ & $f(w_k) = 0$. Then $f(z) = 0$ $\forall z \in D$

The proof is as follows:

$f$ is holomorphic at $z_0 \in D$ then I can find $R>0$ where $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ for $|z-z_0| < R$

Case 1: all $a_n = 0$, this is trivial
case 2: A finite $a_n = 0$, say $N-1$, i.e. $a_0 = a_1 =...=a_{N-1} = 0$ but $a_N \not= 0$
Then we can express $f(z) = a_N(z-z_0)^Ng(z)$ where $g(z)$ is another power series and is holomorphic on $D(z_0,R)$ and $g(z_0) = 1$ by construction

by the intertia principle, for some $\delta > 0$ $g(z )\not = 0$ for $z \in D(z_0,\delta)$

Hence we have $f(z) = a_N(z-z_0)g(z)$ and $f(z) = 0 \iff z = z_0$, so $f(z) \not = 0 \forall z \in D'(z_0,\delta)$ where$D'(z_0,\delta)$ represents the punctured disc. This is a contradiction as we had that $f(w_k) = 0$.

I understand the proof till this point, OK it's a contradiction - but what did we assume wrong and how can we finish the proof? I do not understand the rest of my notes to finish the proof

Comment: the contradiction is to the fact that only finitely may $a_n = 0.$

Comment: @kris could you elaborate I don't see how that's a contradiction, I don't see where it was implied that $a_N = 0$

Comment: @krish nevermind I see. So Case 2 is false and we have all $a_n = 0$, do you know how to proceed to finish the proof?

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089954/explanation-of-this-proof-of-the-principle-of-analytic-continuation

Comment: OP, FYI you should use the tag [tag:proof-explanation] for questions where you are confused about a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above argument is not *completely* clear to me. So I'm giving you another way of approach:

*Let $D$ be a domain and let $f$ be an analytic function on $D.$ Suppose $f$ is not identically zero. Then the zeros of $f$ are isolated.*

Let $U := \{z \in D: f^{(m)}(z) = 0, \forall m \geq 0 \}.$ Suppose $z_0 \in U.$ Consider the power series expression of $f$ in a nbd of $z_0: f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0}a_n(z - z_0)^n.$ We have $a_n = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}.$ So $a_n = 0, \forall n \geq 0 \Rightarrow$ every element in *this* nbd belongs to $U.$ Showing that $U$ is an open set. Now suppose $z_0 \notin U,$ so $f^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0,$ for some $n.$ Then $f^{(n)}(z) \neq 0$ for every $z$ in some nbd of $z_0$ and so *this* nbd is contained in $D-U.$ This shows that $D -U$ is open. Since $D$ is connected, either $U = D$ or $U = \emptyset.$ But $U \neq D.$ So $U = \emptyset. $ This shows that each zero of $f$ is of finite order. If $z_0$ is a zero of $f$ of order $N,$ say, then $f(z) = (z - z_0)^Nh(z)$ where $h(z)$ is analytic near $z_0$ and $h(z_0) \neq 0.$ This shows that $z_0$ is the only zero of $f$ in an nbd of $z_0.$