# Explanation of this proof of the principle of analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

[image: a]
[image: b]

I am confused about the last paragraph,

He states that we choose a point $z_1$ inside the disk, and draw another disk around $z_1$ with radius $\delta_1$ Then says "f is identically zero on this new disk" - could someone explain why $f$ is identically zero on this new disk, when only a part of the disk is contained in $D(z_0,\delta)$ (which we proved $f$ is zero on $D(z_0, \delta)$).

Comment: This wasn't from a book it was from some notes I found online. I can send you the PDF if you email me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is zero in the intersection, so also is zero in a sequence of points with limit $z_1$.

Comment: could you expand, I do not understand. OK it is zero in the intersection, but what do you mean is zero in a sequence of points with limit $z_1$ and how does it mean it is $0$ in the whole disk

Comment: @james1395, take a sequence of points in the intersection with limit $z_1$. Apply the first part of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a $z_1 \in \Omega$ which is in the boundary of $D(z_0, \delta).$ Then there exists a sequence $(w_k), w_k \in D(z_0, \delta)$ such that $w_k \rightarrow z_1.$ Obviously, $w_k \neq z_1, \forall k$ and $f(w_k) = 0, \forall k.$ So by using an argument as used previously, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $f$ vanishes identically on $B(z_1, \delta_1)$ and so on.

I think there is a mistake in the proof. If we choose $z_1 \in D(z_0, \delta)$ and try to use the same argument then we will end up with an $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $f$ vanishes identically on $B(z_1, \delta_1).$ It's not completely clear (at least to me) why $B(z_1, \delta_1)$ can not be completely inside $B(z_0, \delta).$  May be I'm missing something.